# Auto Cad MEP 2011

Tags: autocad

How to Get Device StyleName in Autocad MEP 2011 through c#

Answer (score 0):

To display style sheet of current layout :

```
Layout layout = LayoutManager.Current.CurrentLayout; 
PlotSettings plotSettings = new PlotSettings(layout.ModelType);
plotSettings.CopyFrom(layout);
MessageBox.Show(plotSettings.CurrentStyleSheet);
```

Comment: I want to know how to get Device Object Style Property Name (Like for Description object.Description)

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. Device -> Plot device ? or display device ?